# Can you measure BOD/COD real time using any sensor?

Tags: geochemistry, remote-sensing, biogeochemistry

There is a requirement to measure BOD/COD in a wastewater treatment plant in real time. Is it possible? And if so are there any sensors available in the market for it?

- COD: [Chemical Oxygen Demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_oxygen_demand)
- BOD: [Biochemical Oxygen Demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemical_oxygen_demand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Realtech.com](http://realtechwater.com/municipal-sewage-monitoring/) has a runtime monitoring senser solution for BOD/COD Sensor.
My understanding is that COD is straight-ward to measure in real-time but BOD monitoring cannot be done in real-time.   The sensor listed uses a BOD equivalent monitoring technique.

The governing environmental regulatory agencies for a specific waste water facility should have public statement of acceptable BOD monitoring methods.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple companies that provide COD sensors...
[Real Tech Inc](https://realtechwater.com), [LAR](https://www.lar.com/products/cod-analysis/cod-analyzer-quickcodultra.html), 
[Detectronic](http://www.detectronic.org/products/the-orakel-system/toc-cod-sensor/), [Endress-Hauser](https://www.endress.com/en/field-instruments-overview/liquid-analysis-product-overview/COD-analyzer-CA80COD), and [YSI](https://www.ysi.com/carbovis)...
but they all use [spectrophotometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometry) methods.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't really use spectrophotometry too easily in a wastewater situation then?  Would be a great answer if you could note why that is (have a hunch, but certainly not familiar with the subject enough!).  Welcome to the site, and thanks for the useful info :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real-time BOD, COD or coliform sensors look at Proteus Instruments. They can provide real time data even in wastewater applications and almost need no maintenance. The results are pretty impressive. http://www.proteus-instruments.com. They now have dealers throughout the world.